# $\sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}y\frac{\theta^ye^{-\theta}}{y!(1-e^{-\theta})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Simplify the series: $$\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}y\frac{\theta^ye^{-\theta}}{y!(1-e^{-\theta})}$$

The solution given is $$\frac{\theta}{1-e^{-\theta}}\left(\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}\frac{\theta^ze^{-\theta}}{z!}\right)=\frac{\theta}{1-e^{-\theta}}$$

I do not understand how the solution is formed. Hope someone could explain it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your attempts and thoughts.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the final answer has $e^{\theta}$ and not $e^{-\theta}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}y\frac{\theta^ye^{-\theta}}{y!(1-e^{-\theta})} 
&=\frac{e^{-\theta}}{(1-e^{-\theta})}\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}y\frac{\theta^y}{y!} \\[2ex]
&=\frac{\theta e^{-\theta}}{(1-e^{-\theta})}\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}\frac{\theta^{y-1}}{(y-1)!} \\[2ex]
&=\frac{\theta e^{-\theta}}{(1-e^{-\theta})}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\frac{\theta^{y}}{y!}
\end{align}$$

Comment: +1, I was trying to follow your answer because it was very dexterous and interesting, but I was literally getting lost in the single line of text, so I did some vertical arranging. I hope you don’t mind; it aids legibility in my opinion.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor. Thank you very much for doing it ! It is much better. Cheers.